# Will the EF Fluent API allow mapping an optional non-standard FK to a non-standard primary key or using non-standard projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Problems: 
I'm working with legacy code, and I am attempting to pull in a related entity, which has a loosely defined relationship between a Code column in one table and a separate Code table. NOTE: **No foreign key was configured** and the reference is based on the string-based "Code" and **not** a primary key.

I'm losing valuable overhead currently, because this relationship is not implied, I am essentially having to sideload this relationship into the primary model. With a collection in the thousands, its costly to have to materialize

An example:

```
public class Problem
{
    int Id
    string ProblemName
    string ProblemCode  <<< this is the foreign key dependency
}

public class Code 
{ 
    int Id
    string Code <<< this is the pseudo-primary key 
    string CodeDescription    
}
```

Possible solutions 2: Model Binding
I have dug through the Entity Framework documentation and I know it is possible to set a unique foreign-key constraint, except that in every case, insofar as I can tell, it always references the explicit primary key of the principal.

> Question 1: Will the EF Fluent API allow mapping an optional non-standard FK to a non-standard primary key

Possible solution 2: Loading the related entity in a context call
This is the less desirable method, but I am currently exploring this, using a foreach to populate the loosely connected entity that way. Unfortunately using Select to project this into the existing composition do not work, as the entities are (sigh) variant child entities and the query call is of the abstract parent entity (The EF entity is "Problem" but the Select would require something like "CarProblem").

> Question 2: Recommended solutions for assigning an entity without using SELECT projections (i do not believe this is present, currently)

Answer (score 0):

> Will the EF Fluent API allow mapping an optional non-standard FK to a non-standard primary key

Yes.  EF doesn't care what the *real* PK is.  Having a unique index in the database is, of course, highly recommended.  But in EF just mark whatever key you want as the Entity Key, and you can use that for Navigation Properties.

eg

```
public class Code 
{ 
    int Id {get;set;}
    [Key]
    string Code {get;set;}
    string CodeDescription  {get;set;}
}
```

EF Core supports alternate keys, but in EF 6 you can only have one key per entity type.